# How to load a csv file into R as a factor for use with glmnet and logistic regression

Tags: r, csv, glmnet

I have a csv file (single column, numeric values) called "y" that consists of zeros and ones where the rows with the value 1 indicate the target variable for logistic regression, and another file called "x" with the same number of rows and with columns of numeric predictor values. How do I load these so that I can then use cv.glmnet, i.e.

```
x <- read.csv('x',header=FALSE,sep=",")
y <- read.csv('y',header=FALSE )
```

is throwing an error

```
Error in y %*% rep(1, nc) : 
requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments
```

when I call

```
cvfit = cv.glmnet(x, y, family = "binomial")
```

I know that "y" should be loaded as a "factor," but how do I do this? My online searches have found all sorts of approaches that have just confused me. What is the simple one-liner to just load this data ready for glmnet?

Comment: `glmnet` expects `y` to be a vector or a two-column matrix. `read.csv` returns a data frame. You can `unlist(y)` a single column data frame to convert it to a vector, or pull out the first column explicitly as a vector with `y[[1]]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cv.glmnet` requires data to be provided in vector or matrix format. You can use the following code

`xmat = as.matrix(x)`

`yvec = as.vector(y)`

Then use

`cvfit = cv.glmnet(xmat, yvec, family = "binomial")`

If you can provide your data in `dput()` format, I can give a try.